# Vector bundle on $\mathbb P^2$ with vanishing second Chern class

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a  rank $2$ vector bundle on $\mathbb P^2$ such that $c_1(E)=-H$ where $H$ is the hyperplane class. If we know that $\chi (\mathbb P^2, E(-1))=0$, then does this mean $c_2(E)=0$? (my calculation using Riemann-Roch obtains this, Please correct me if this is wrong)

Can we say that $E$ is a twist of $\Omega_{\mathbb P^2}(2)$?

Any suggestion, comment or remark is welcome.

Comment: $c_1(\Omega(2)) = H$, not $-H$.

Comment: @Sasha, In my question I am asking if $E$ is an appropriate twist of $\Omega(2)$ (not necessarily exactly $\Omega(2)$)

Comment: The only twist of $\Omega$ which has $c_1=-H$ is $E=\Omega(1)$. Then $\chi(E(-1))\neq 0$.

Comment: @Mohan, Thank you very much for pointing it out ( I missed this easy observation). Can we specifically identify such a bundle $E$ or at least can we say something about their properties?

Comment: Maybe it is worth explaining the motivation behind your question.

Comment: @Sasha, Let $E$ be a rank $2$ vector bundle on the projective plane whose $H^1$ vanishes for all twists except $1$, then one can show that it has properties mentioned as above. In a recent preprint It was then deduced that $E$ is isomorphic to $\Omega_{\mathbb P^2}(2)$. I guess this is due to an incorrect calculation $c2=1$ from the Euler Characteristic condition. I was trying to see if something can still be said about $E$ in this corrected  $c2=0$.

Comment: What you wrote about the vanishing of $H^1$ is not true for $\Omega(2)$, so I suspect that you confused some other details as well.

Comment: @Sasha, Yes you are right. $\Omega(2)$ does not satisfy that $H^1$ property. That is exactly what I wrote in my previous comment (The miscalculation of $c2$ in that paper). Now that we know it is not $\Omega(2)$, I'm trying to understand what is the correct identification of such $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be a rank two vector bundle on the projective plane such that $H^1(E(k))=0$ for all $k\neq 0$ and $h^1(E)=r>0$. Then $E=\Omega$.

Since $H^1(E)=\operatorname{Ext}^1(O,E)$, we have a universal extension,
$$0\to E\to F\to O^r\to 0.$$
It is immediate that $H^1(F(k))=0$ for all $k$ and thus by Horrock's criterion, $F$ is a direct sum of line bundles, $F=\oplus O(a_i)$. Again, it is clear that all the $a_i<0$. Since $H^1(E(1))=0$, the map $H^0(F(1))\to H^0(O^r(1))$ is onto. But $h^0(F(1))\leq r+2$ and $h^0(O^r(1))=3r$. So, $3r\leq r+2$ and thus $r=1$ and all $a_i=-1$. Rest is clear.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a nice Answer. I just want to ask if instead $E$ is a rank $2$ bundle on the plane with $c_1( E)= H$ and $ c_2=1$ and it is known that $H^1( E(-2)) \neq 0$ and $H^1(E(k))=0$ for $k \neq -2$, then can we adapt the technique used in your answer to deduce that $E \cong \Omega(2)$?

Comment: @Sherlock I am not sure what you are asking. Replacing your $E$ by $E(-2)$, it gives my situation and thus $E(-2)=\Omega$. The chern classes play no role.

Comment: I understand now that replacing $E$ by $E(-2)$ the same thing works. The thing about the Chern class is that if a rank $2$ vector bundle $E$ is ACM except for one twist on a plane, then it must satisfy the conditions that I mentioned in my previous comment.